# group by with sum

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Simplifying I have something like this:

```
select register_date,count(*)
from USER
group by register_date;
```

and result is:

```
2016-01-20  10
2016-01-21  5
2016-01-22  8
```

This shows me that at first day 10 users registered than 5 and 8 next days.
I need to have a sum of registered users:

```
2016-01-20  10
2016-01-21  15 (10+5)
2016-01-22  23 (10+5+8)
```

Any ideas how to get it ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum.  You can do this with an aggregation query, even:

```
select register_date, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by register_date) as running_count
from USER
group by register_date
order by register_date;
```